# How to delete file using lwc from salesforce

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, community, aura

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Files">
        <template for:each={fileList} for:item="file">
            <div key={file.value} class="slds-box">
                <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
                    <div class="slds-col slds-large-size_4-of-12 slds-medium-size_8-of-12 slds-size_12-of-12">
                        <p>{file.label}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-col slds-large-size_4-of-12 slds-medium-size_8-of-12 slds-size_12-of-12">
                        <p>{file.value}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-col slds-large-size_4-of-12 slds-medium-size_4-of-12 slds-size_12-of-12">
                        <lightning-button label="Delete" variant="brand" data-id={file.value} onclick={deleteSelectedRecords}></lightning-button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
        </template>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

JS file

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api,track } from "lwc";
import getRelatedFilesByRecordId from "@salesforce/apex/DeleteFileController.getRelatedFilesByRecordId";
import deleteSelectedfile from "@salesforce/apex/DeleteFileController.deleteSelectedfile";
import { deleteRecord } from "lightning/uiRecordApi";
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
import {ShowToastEvent} from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

export default class FileList extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId
    
    @track fileList =[]
    recordIds;
    @wire(getRelatedFilesByRecordId, {recordId: '$recordId'})

    wiredResult({data, error}){
      if(data)
      {
        console.log(data)
        this.fileList = Object.keys(data).map(item=>({"label":data[item],"value": item}))
        console.log(this.fileList)
      }
      if(error)
      {
        console.log(error)
      }
    }
    
    deleteSelectedRecords(event)
    {
      console.log('id of button:' , event.currentTarget.dataset.id)
      let recordIds = event.currentTarget.dataset.id
      console.log('recordId set: ',recordIds)

      
      deleteSelectedfile({recordIds})
      .then(result => {
        this.dispatchEvent(
          new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Success',
            message: 'Selected record is deleted!',
            variant: 'success',
          }),
        );
        return refreshApex(this.fileList);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.message = undefined;
        this.error = error;
        this.dispatchEvent(
          new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Error creating records',
            message: error.body.pageError[0].message,
            variant: 'error',
          
          }),
        );
        console.log("error", JSON.stringify(this.error));
      });
      
}
```

apex class

```
public with sharing class DeleteFileController {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static Map<Id, String> getRelatedFilesByRecordId(String recordId) {
        List<ContentDocumentLink> files = [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId = :recordId];
        List<ID> fileIDs = new List<ID>();
        for (ContentDocumentLink docLink : files)
        {
            fileIDs.add(docLink.ContentDocumentId);
        }
         
        List<ContentVersion> docs = [SELECT ContentDocumentId, FileExtension, Title FROM ContentVersion WHERE ContentDocumentId IN: fileIDs];
        Map<ID, String> mapIdTitle = new Map<ID, String>();
        for(ContentVersion docLink : docs)
        {
            mapIdTitle.put(docLink.ContentDocumentId, docLink.Title);
        }
        return mapIdTitle;
    }
@AuraEnabled
    public static Id deleteSelectedfile(Id docIds){
        try{
            System.debug('inside apex class');
            delete [SELECT Id FROM ContentDocument WHERE Id=:docIds];
            return 'SUCCESS';
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            throw new AuraHandledException(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
 }
```

i am able to fetch file and also in deleteSelectedRecords(event) i am getting file id in recordIds but it is not going inside apex class method and not performing dml operation. can anyone help me in this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change return type of method

> public static Id deleteSelectedfile(Id docIds)

to

> public static String deleteSelectedfile(Id docIds)

Comment: I tried this but its not working its still not going inside apex class not even deleting file

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with how you are calling you apex method and passing the required parameters.

Your apex method definition is :-

```
public static Id deleteSelectedfile(Id docIds){
```

when you call this in lwc and invoke, it expects you pass the **docIds** should be passed. but you are calling it as:-

```
deleteSelectedfile({recordIds})
```

where as you should be calling it as below:-

```
deleteSelectedfile({ docIds: this.recordIds })
```

which sets the value of parameter in apex class.

You can read more here on how you can call imperative an apex method [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/apex_call_imperative)

Comment: thanks for help !! combination of both answer worked for me